# Scroll Bar in iframe - content has 100% height

Tags: css, html

I have following index.html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>    
    html, body {
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body style="height:100%;">
<div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
  <div id="theHead" style="height:10%; ">

  </div>
  <div id="theMain" style="height:80%;">

  </div>
  <div id="theBottom" style="height:10%;">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is inside iframe:

```
<iframe id="theIframe" src="index.html" width="800px" height="450px">
   Hello World...
</iframe>
```

I see that a scroll bar appears on iframe, that allows for slight(very little) scrolling.

***Why is any scrolling happening?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see.. Because you must change browser css defaults use in [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Example delete margin:

index.html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>    
    html, body {
        height:100%;
        margin:0px; //--> added this line
    }
</style>
</head>

<body style="height:100%;">
<div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
  <div id="theHead" style="height:10%; ">

  </div>
  <div id="theMain" style="height:80%;">

  </div>
  <div id="theBottom" style="height:10%;">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Firefox default stylesheet file](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/layout/style/html.css)

[Webkit default stylesheet file](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
<iframe id="theIframe" src="index.html" width="800px" height="450px">
   Hello World...
</iframe>
```

try using

```
<iframe id="theIframe" src="index.html" width="800px" height="450px">Hello   World...</iframe>
```

and add scrolling="no" if you don't want to see the scrollbar on your iframe.